# Use contents of a different JSON as an input to modify using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a config file as follows:

```
env_config.json:

{
  "config":"GLOBAL_CONFIG"
}

global_config.json:
{
  "key":"value"
}
```

before deployment, I need to change the value of GLOBAL_CONFIG with an stringify json of global_config.json. so env_config.json should look like this:

```
env_config.json
{
  "config":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"
}
```

to achieve the above output I did the following:

```
global_config=$(jq -c '.|tostring'  global_config.json)
sed  -i "s/\"GLOBAL_CONFIG\"/$global_config/1" env_config.json
```

Unfortunately, this unescape the double quotes which makes my final JSON invalid

```
{
   "config":"{"key":"value"}".   #please note the inner double quotes are not escaped anymore
}
```

Is there a way to make sure the replacement with `sed` carries out with the escaped double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an intermediary temp file:

```
jq -c '.|tostring' global_config.json > temp.json
```

Escape the backslashes:

```
sed -i 's/\\/\\\\/g' temp.json
global_config=$(cat temp.json)
```

Then the following will work, as only one backslash will be removed

```
sed  -i "s/\"GLOBAL_CONFIG\"/$global_config/1" env_config.json
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing can be done in `jq` itself, which can slurp an input file and the contents of which can be used to update another file as below. The `tojson` function encodes your already existing string as JSON string with escapes added

```sh
jq --slurpfile gc global_config.json '{ config: $gc[0] | tojson }' env_config.json
```

If you know, there isn't a stream of objects (a static file) in the config, you could use `--argfile` and drop the `[0]` on `$gc` variable.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is env_config.json is a very complex structure. and depending on env it can vary quite a bit. Obviously, for the purpose of this question, I have simplified it.

Comment: @nafas: What would you like to change about it? This is what you asked in your Q. What did you mean by a complex structure? And could you adopt this to your actual JSON?

Comment: env_config.json is an array with many objects inside it, some of the objects(or their inner objects) "may" have an attributes "config" and if the value is "GLOBAL_CONFIG" then I need to change its value with the global_config.json value as a string. (PS I didn't design this system..... :/ :/ :/ )

Comment: @nafas: Add all the above details to the Q above and provide a equivalent dummy representation of your JSON. That's the only way, I can modify my answer further